# I get the error that there can't be converted from double to int

Tags: java, casting

This is another newbie question. I have been working this type of error for the last couple of days and have been getting nowhere so it is time to ask you, the adoring wonders of the Java world.

I'm getting the error that there cannot be converted from double to int.

This is the code that I have written:

```
out.printf("Enter the price of the first article:");
    double priceFirstArticle = in.nextDouble();
    int i = priceFirstArticle; //ERROR*****//

    out.printf("Enter the price of the second article:");
    double priceSecondArticle = in.nextDouble();
    int s = priceSecondArticle; //ERROR*****//

    out.printf("Enter the price of the third article:");
    double priceThirdArticle = in.nextDouble();
    int t = priceThirdArticle; //ERROR*****//
```

How can I fix this error?

Thank you for your help,

Northwill

Comment: change `int` to `double`

Comment: Please read: _[What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)_

Comment: you can not convert double to int this way. Please read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @L.NorthWill : Any of our answers worked for you? If yes please accept one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a `double` to an `int` you need to explicitly cast it

```
double priceFirstArticle = in.nextDouble();
int i = (int) priceFirstArticle;
```

or change double to int as follows :

```
int priceFirstArticle = in.nextInt();
int i = priceFirstArticle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting from a `double` to an `int` may lose information, so Java doesn't allow it out of the box. If you want to do this, you need to be explicit about it, e.g., by casting:

```
int i = (int) priceFirstArticle;
// Here-^
```

Answer (score 0):

There remains a lot of ways...

you can not just type `int i = priceFirstArticle;` to convert it into `int`.

Some of them are

```
Double d = new Double();
int i = d.intValue();
```

or

you can use `Math.round(double)`.

but the first one is much preferable.

Answer (score -1):

first, You have to use wrapper class (Double, Integer, ecc) for the primitive type (double, int,...).

In java > 1.5 boxing and unboxing is automatic.

```
Double priceFirstArticle = in.nextDouble();
    int  i = priceFirstArticle.intValue();
 ........
```